# HTML5 textfield on IOS Keyboard: How to jump to next field with enter, leaving keyboard open

Tags: ios, html, keyboard

I am implementing a HTML5/javascript "mobile" site and I have some textfields where the user should be able to jump from one textfield to another using 'enter'. On the last textfield(when some specific requirements are met) the user is sending this "form" to a server.
I implemented this using javascript, catching the enter key and setting the focus on the next textfield. It works perfectly on pc but on ios, after executing the first "enter" and setting the focus on the next textfield, the ios keyboard closes and no textfield is focused.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify that you are using the native 'popup' keyboard and not a jquery or other virtual one?

Comment: yes I am using the native keyboard.

Comment: The enter key performs a form submit. just capture the onSubmit event, prevent default action and set focus to the input you want focused.